# In an Apache Storm topology, is there an internal queue between a spout and a bolt?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-storm

In order to be compliant with **a specific RabbitMQ Message broker implementation**, it is **critical** that the spout **consume and acknowledge as fast as possible** the broadcasted messages.

The specs of the Message Broker instance insists on the fact that the consumer must implement an in memory queue in order to not delay the acknowledgement in case of a slow processing time.

Is there **such an implicit queue between a spout and a bolt** ? Do I have to implement an in-memory queue within the bolt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a queue between spouts and bolts, [as stated here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/).

If this won't help you, you can create a internal buffer in the spout and ack as soon as you insert the tuple in that internal buffer.